# NetworkStream ReadAsync cancellation

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, networkstream, cancellation

I am trying to add a "timeout" for the `ReadAsync` method from a `NetworkStream`.

I want to cancel the `ReadAsync` after a specific time.

For example:

```
ctsTimeout.CancelAfter(10);

int bytesRead = await nsStream.ReadAsync(newArr, 0, newArr.Length, ctsTimeout.Token);
```

But the method is still waiting for a response from the server.

Is it possible to cancel this method in its reading state?

Comment: The main issue I have with this is cleanup after a ReadAsync or WriteAsync completes. If I dispose of a class that contains the read/write buffer too early, an illegal operation can occur. Don't dispose of the class, and you may wind up with a memory leak. I remedied this by adding Dispose( ) to the Read/Write Task using ContinueWith(() => classThatHoldsTheBuffer.Dispose()).

Answer (score 2):

`NetworkStream` (or `Stream` by inheritance) doesn't really support cancellation.  The `ReadAsync` method accepts a cancellation token, sure; but that really just allows you to know if a cancellation was requested before the read completed.  The `ReadAsync` really just wraps `BeginRead` and `EndRead`--which offer no way to cancel the read operation.

To really cancel a read you need to dispose or `Close` the `NetworkStream` object.